# How can I switch an OIC Connector based on a given value

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm new to the OIC environment, migrated from OSB 11g.

We have a large number of databases with the same structure, and need to access then based on a given input.

In OSB 11g one can change the JCA's header with a new datasource name, and I would like to do the same in OIC or to find a different solution (and no, a switch on the input will have some 50 route options).
Any ideas?

Comment: It's seems that there is no way to change the connection itself, but is there and way of changing the connection details during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we've decided not to work with OIC due to the fact that you cannot amend the JCA's connecting during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the data may suit what you are looking for - https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/mapper-user/mapping-data.html

Also view Modifying an Integration - https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/integrations-user/modifying-integration.html

Comment: No, it's not. 
We need the modification on runtime.